# How to show unbundled individual javascript and css of my rails web-application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, nginx-config

I want to show unbundled javascript and css of my web-application to a UI developer. I have tried adding `require 'sprockets/railties'
 config.assets.debug = true`

in my production.rb, but it did not work and I can still see bundled, uglified css/js in my browser sources.
I tried running my production in development mode by adding `rack_env development` in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` http block, but I get Bad Request due to following error:-

```
invalid number of arguments in "rack_env" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:16
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try purging and recompiling your assets by any chance? Depending on your deploy method, production assets may not be recompiled on every deploy / application start.

1. `rake assets:clean` (`rake assets:clobber`) for Rails 4+
2. `rake assets:precompile`

By default, `config.assets.debug = true` is what controls this 'bundling' behavior.

You might also try to comment out 
`config.assets.js_compressor = ...` or
`config.assets.css_compressor = ...` 
if you have any of those in your production.rb.

Another reason may be any sort of external cache, depending on where you host your app: Cloudflare or [Heroku Asset Pipeline Cache](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#caching) (those usually cache based on MD5 of your assets). 
And the last but not the least is... browser cache, just in case :)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am getting error `Don't know how to build task 'assets:clean'`

Comment: My bad, it's a different task name for Rails 4+. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Its working in safari browser and not in other browsers. (Safari is unbundling even without following above steps)